# Create a copy of a UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Because objects are reference types, not value types, if you set a `UIView` equal to another `UIView`, the views are the same object. If you modify one you'll modifying the other as well.

I have an interesting situation where I would like to add a `UIView` as a subview in another view, then I make some modifications, and those modifications should not affect the original `UIView`. How can I make a copy of the `UIView` so I can ensure I add that copy as a subview instead of a reference to the original `UIView`?

Note that I can't recreate the view in the same way the original was created, I need some way to create a copy given any `UIView` object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't arbitrarily copy an object. Only objects that implement the `NSCopying` protocol can be copied.

However, there is a workaround: Since `UIView`s can be serialized to disk (e.g. to load from a XIB), you could use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to create a serialized `NSData` describing your view, then de-serialize that again to get an independent but identical object.

Comment: @DannyBravo Where do you get that from? My UIView.h only declares conformance to NSCoding, UIAppearance, UIAppearanceContainer, UIDynamicItem, UITraitEnvironment, UICoordinateSpace, UIFocusItem and CALayerDelegate. No NSCopying in there as far as I can see.

Comment: You are totally right, I got mixed up there for a bit. I'm removing my answer.

Answer (score 140):

You can make an UIView extension. In example snippet below, function copyView returns an AnyObject so you could copy any subclass of an UIView, *ie* UIImageView. If you want to copy *only* UIView you can change the return type to UIView.

```
//MARK: - UIView Extensions

extension UIView
{
    func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let sourceView = UIView()
let copiedView: UIView = sourceView.copyView()
```

Comment: How is this not a factory method on UIView?

Comment: But it seems to lose IBOutlet bindings

Comment: Doesn't work if I have a custom view. the view losses it's view properties and elements.

Comment: Then your view is not correctly implementing `-initWithCoder:` and `-encodeWithCoder:` to serialize all its properties.

Comment: Methods `archivedData(withRootObject:)` and `unarchivedObject(with:)` are *deprecated* as of iOS 12.0.

Comment: is there a way to copy all subviews within a View?

Comment: @DavidJames answer for iOS 12 works within a do { try catch {

Answer (score 18):

**Update for iOS >= 12.0**

Methods `archivedData(withRootObject:)` and `unarchivedObject(with:)` are deprecated as of iOS 12.0.

Here is an update to @Ivan Porcolab's answer using the newer API (since 11.0), also made more general to support other types.

```
extension NSObject {
    func copyObject<T:NSObject>() throws -> T? {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:self, requiringSecureCoding:false)
        return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? T
    }
}
```

Comment: not working for subclass , like class MyView:UIView , then while copying MyView it returns UIView instead.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati there's no reason it won't work. Actually, I tried it and it did work.

Comment: 'unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:) instead

Answer (score 6):

This answer shows how to do what @uliwitness suggested. That is, get an identical object by archiving it and then unarchiving it. (It is also basically what Ivan Porkolab did in his answer, but in a more readable format, I think.)

```
let myView = UIView()

// create an NSData object from myView
let archive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myView)

// create a clone by unarchiving the NSData
let myViewCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archive) as! UIView
```

## Notes

- Unarchiving the data creates an object of type `AnyObject`. We used `as! UIView` to type cast it back to a `UIView` since we know that's what it is. If our view were a `UITextView` then we could type cast it `as! UITextView`.
- The `myViewCopy` no longer has a parent view.
- [Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131351/uiview-duplicate#comment5258088_2131370) mention some problems when working with `UIImage`. However, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334593/3681880) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9282203/3681880) answer.

*Updated to Swift 3.0*

Comment: I implemented this and for a second I thought it was working. But i'm copying an UIView that has subviews and the result i'm getting are the subviews, but not the view itself. I saw it debugging the view hierarchy. The view that im copying is an IBOutlet instead of `UIView()`. Does it sounds familiar?

Comment: I'm sorry. When debugging a little more what is happening is that in the copied view I get `view.top = view.bottom` as a constraint and that's why i don`t see it in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you should link you UIView with a .nib and just create a new one.

Property will not be the same, but you keep appearance and methods.

Comment: That's also a good approach. If you already have a XIB that you define the object in, and you're mostly concerned about setting it up correctly, and the attributes you change on it are few, you can just load the XIB a second time (you can have XIBs with a single free-floating view in them).

Comment: if it's xib based.

Answer (score 1):

An addition solution could be to just create a new `UIView` and then copy over any critical properties. This may not work in the OP's case, but it could very well work for other cases.

For example, with a `UITextView`, probably all you would need is the frame and attributed text:

```
let textViewCopy = UITextView(frame: textView.frame)
textViewCopy.attributedText = textView.attributedText
```

Answer (score -1):

This is mostly just an update for iOS 12+

```
extension NSObject {
func copyObject<T:NSObject>() throws -> T? {
    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:self, requiringSecureCoding:false)
    return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? T
}
```

Comment: `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData` is deprecated in iOS 12+

Answer (score -4):

Additionally you can use this pattern to copy View controller view

```
let vc = UIViewController() 
let anotherVc = UIViewController()
vc.view = anotherVc.copyView()
```

You may need this for caching view controller or cloning.