# Copy UIView with UIView extension stored variable

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, extension-methods

I want to create a copy of a UIView and also copy an additional variable, by using extensions.

To copy the UIView I'm using: (from [Create a copy of a UIView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121655/create-a-copy-of-a-uiview-in-swift/34404432#34404432))

```
extension UIView
{
    func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
    }
}
```

To add a variable on UIView I'm using:
https://marcosantadev.com/stored-properties-swift-extensions/

```
extension PropertyStoring {
    func getAssociatedObject(_ key: UnsafeRawPointer!, defaultValue: T) -> T {
        guard let value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, key) as? T else {
            return defaultValue
        }
        return value
    }
}

enum ToggleState {
    case on
    case off
}


extension UIView: PropertyStoring {
    typealias T = ToggleState
    private struct CustomProperties {
        static var toggleState = ToggleState.off
    }
    var toggleState: ToggleState {
        get {
            return getAssociatedObject(&CustomProperties.toggleState, defaultValue: CustomProperties.toggleState)
        }
        set {
            return objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &CustomProperties.toggleState, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when copying a UIView, it's subviews won't keep the correct toggle state.

Did anyone get a solution which can not only copy the UIView but also keep the variables from an extension?

P.S. I cannot use a subclass as a solution

Comment: You can create a custom UIView subclass with the stored property you want and then try to copy that view.

Comment: @RatneshJain I should have mentioned I cannot use a subclass, added that in the question

Comment: If you are using NSKeyedArchiver your properties have to be encoded and decoded through encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder.