# How to make a copy of UIView in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios16

I was using the below func to Make Copy of a UIView :

```swift
extension UIView {
    func copyObject<T:NSObject>() throws -> T? {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:self, requiringSecureCoding:false)
        return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? T
    }
}
```

Recently I have updated my app to support iOS 16. I am getting the below warning for the above code:

> 'unarchiveObject(with:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead

> 'archivedData(withRootObject:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead

After fixing the warning The code looks like this:

```
func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
    let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:self, requiringSecureCoding:false)
    return try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIView.self, from:data!)  as! T
    //return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
}
```

Now when I try to copy, I am getting below error

> error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'UIView' does not adopt it." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'UIView' does not adopt it.}

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why are you trying to copy views in the first place?

Comment: I want to pass the copied view to a third party to generate a PDF file from this view

Comment: Why do you need a *copy* then? Does the third party modify the view in some way? And why can't you just run the code you used to create the view a second time?

Comment: Yes, the third party is modifying the view it is adding extra blank spaces at the bottom. Till now the above code was working fine but once I updated my app to iOS16, I had to update the deployment target to iOS13 & I ran into this issue.

Comment: *That* sounds like your actual problem. I'd suggest that you [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of that problem instead.

Comment: I have taken a reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52927098/12797715, but it seems to be no longer working in iOS16. I have a similar use case.